MariaDB 11.4.2 yum package does not include mariadb-upgrade or mariadb-devel
I'm trying to install MariaDb 11.4.2 in an AlmaLinux 8 server.
I've installed the MariaDb repository with this:
 #  Download it
 wget -N  https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup
 #  Check checksum
 echo "26e5bf36846003c4fe455713777a4e4a613da0df3b7f74b6dad1cb901f324a84  mariadb_repo_setup"        | sha256sum -c -
 #  Install the repository:
 chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
 ./mariadb_repo_setup
 #  Install mariadb:
 dnf install mariadb mariadb-devel mariadb-backup -y

The server is properly installed with version 11.4.2, but:

I'm missing the mariadb-upgrade command.
Also the mariadb-develpackage is not comming from the MariaDB repository but from the Alma 'appstream' repository, and the version is not 11.4.2.

Any ideas on how to completely install MariaDb 11.4.2 (latest stable release) on AlbumaLinux8 so that is includes both mariadb-devel package and the command mariadb-upgrade?

I found the issue: it seems the package names are case sensitive.
The correct installation command is:
 dnf install MariaDB MariaDB-devel MariaDB-backup -y

